# How to correctly create a CMake file for a modular project

Tags: c++, cmake, netbeans-8, clion

Suppose C++ project A as my main program and project B is my module that is shared object (.so). Project A consist source and headers that is common between both projects. Project A load module .so file in runtime.

**Project A:**

```
class-AI.cpp (It contains function funcA)
class-AI.h

class-AII.cpp
class-AII.h

class-AIII.cpp
class-AIII.h

main.cpp
```

**Project B: (Shared Object)**

```
class-BI.cpp (Its inherit from class-AI)
class-BI.h
```

With following CMake files both project build successfully.

**Project A CMakefile:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ProjectA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.cpp
        class-AI.cpp
        class-AI.h
        class-AII.cpp
        class-AII.h
        class-AIII.cpp
        class-AIII.h)

add_executable(ProjectA ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH /opt/ProjectA/bin/)
```

**Project B CMakefile:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ProjectB)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES class-BI.cpp class-BI.h)
add_library(ProjectB SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})    
set_target_properties(ProjectB PROPERTIES
        PREFIX ""
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY /opt/ProjectA/bin/)
```

But at runtime Project A following error will be appear:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN6class-AI4funcAEv
```

How can I add dependency to project B correctly using CMake file and solve this error? (Actually I want to change my netbeans C++ project to Jetbrains CLion)

Comment: See [CMake/Tutorials/Exporting and Importing Targets](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets#Importing_Targets). You need to make Project A CMake file aware of Project B. There are several ways, so I would probably add something starting with `add_library(ProjectB SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)` ...

Comment: @Florian: Thanks bro. I did what you said and my problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763489/florian) for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519666/how-to-correctly-create-a-cmake-file-for-a-modular-project?noredirect=1#comment70258627_41519666). My problem solved with adding this lines to Project A CMake file:

```
add_library(ProjectB SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(ProjectB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/opt/ProjectA/bin/ProjectB.so")
target_link_libraries(ProjectA ProjectB)
```