# Using cmake with a shared (dynamic) library

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, cygwin

I'm trying to use a simple shared library that I made with a file that just contains a main method.
I first ran `cmake .` which worked fine and didn't return any errors.

Then I ran `make` but got this error:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target myprog
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable myprog.exe
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lhello-user
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang-3.8: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/build.make:95: myprog.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(LIB_EXAMPLE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
add_executable(myprog main.c)
target_link_libraries(myprog hello-user)
```

The library exists inside of `/usr/local/lib/` as `libhello-user.dll.a`

Note: Im using `Cygwin` for `cmake` and `make`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly create a CMake file for a modular project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519666/how-to-correctly-create-a-cmake-file-for-a-modular-project). See [CMake/Tutorials/Exporting and Importing Targets](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets). I would probably add something starting with `add_library(hello-user SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)`.

Comment: But im not creating a new library? im trying to use a current one. ?

Comment: Yes, but the solution is the same. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

See [CMake/Tutorials/Exporting and Importing Targets](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets).

You either have:

- to name a full path for the library

  - CMake is not searching for it automatically
  - you would have to add something like `find_library(_lib_path NAMES hello-user)`
- or - better - put those into an IMPORTED target

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
  project(LIB_EXAMPLE)

  add_library(hello-user SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
  set_target_properties(
      hello-user 
      PROPERTIES 
          IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libhello-user.dll
          IMPORTED_IMPLIB   /usr/local/lib/libhello-user.dll.a
  )    

  add_executable(myprog main.c)
  target_link_libraries(myprog hello-user)
  ```

Comment: Thank you this works. Could you explain why my way didnt work?

Comment: You didn't declare that your executable depended on this library. That's the only way CMake can tell you care about that specific library out of all the ones it could find for you.